# Manually stop jquery-ui sliding event for element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, slider

I need to manually stop an element from being slided (i used `.slider()` to create the slider). How can i achieve this?

I need to do this because the jquery-ui slider has issues when inside an iframe. So far i have managed to create a function that change the value of the slider however i had no luck trying to active the stop, or mouseup event of the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent found how to solve this, so what i did was prevent the sliding event from doing anything at start with this:

```
 $('.slider',$document).slider({start:function(event,ui){return false;}});
```

That i way i can have a total manual control over the slider.

If you are curios about why i needed to do this you can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817109/creating-a-draggable-object-in-a-iframe-from-outside)